# Using re.sub() to replace some part of a string

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, replace

#### background

I'm trying to use `re` to replace some value in a string. Essentially, replace the **first detected int** (in a **specific pattern**) with **1**.

Examples:

```
{1}        -> {1}
{2}        -> {1}
{3,}       -> {1,}
{3,16}     -> {1,16}
ab{3,16}   -> ab{1,16}
5a4b{3,16} -> 5a4b{1,16}
{1,4}      -> {1,4}
```

#### attempt

```
import re

pattern = '.*{(\d+)}|{(\d+),}|{(\d+),\d+}'
string = 'ab{3,16}'
print re.sub(pattern, '1', string)
```

But I get `ab1` instead of `ab{1,16}`

Comment: What should `'{3}{3}'` be converted to?

Comment: @EricDuminil That's an interesting question. such use case is not exepcted in my case but it would be interesting to know how to resolve that. for me, `{3}{3}` should be converted to `{1}{1}`

Comment: I updated my answer, which seems to pass all your specs.

Comment: And you well deserve an accept for your time & effort.

Comment: My pleasure. I'm learning Python, and SO is a great way to learn new stuff!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to replace the `{}` or `,`, so you could use [positive lookaheads and lookbehinds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in order to make sure the int is :

- after a `{` with : `(?<={)`
- before a `}` or a `,` with : `(?=}|,)`

If you want to want to replace only the first occurence in the whole string, you can set the 4th argument of [`sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) to 1. In that case, `{3}{3}` will be converted to `{1}{3}`. UPDATE : You don't want it. :)

```
import re

pattern = '(?<={)\d+(?=}|,)'
string = 'ab{3,16}'
print re.sub(pattern, '1', string)
```

Here are some tests :

```
import re

def replace_first_int(string):
  pattern = '(?<={)\d+(?=}|,)'
  return re.sub(pattern, '1', string)

print replace_first_int('{1}')
# {1}
print replace_first_int('{2}')
# {1}
print replace_first_int('{3,}')
# {1,}
print replace_first_int('{3')
# {3
print replace_first_int('{3,16}')
# {1,16}
print replace_first_int('{1,4}')
# {1,4}
print replace_first_int('{3}{3}')
# {1}{1}
print replace_first_int('ab5')
# ab5
print replace_first_int('5a4b{3,16}')
# 5a4b{1,16}
```

Answer (score 2):

When doing a replace with regex the whole matched string will be replaced. As you match the whole `{1,16}`, it is replaced by `1` accordingly.

For your samples `(?<=\{)\d+` will work as pattern and can then replaced by `1`, like

```
import re

pattern = '(?<={)\d+'
string = 'ab{3,16}'
print re.sub(pattern, '1', string)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your pattern is always in the specified format (as in your examples), this will be enough:

```
print re.sub(r'{\d+', '{1', string, count=1)
```

Comment: You are right. However, I've updated the question. The expected format is just slightly more complex